# Learning pointers by implementing a basic linked list with tests

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list, pointers

I wanted to learn about pointers and someone suggested that I give C a try, so I went through [Linked List Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf) from Stanford CS library, implemented some of the code (and tried to improve the code a bit as I went), as well as wrote "unit tests" (to the extent you can call them such in C).

I'm using "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86" compiler, though I would expect it should work fine with other compilers as well. When run, it prints the following output to `stdout`:

> ```
> C:\Scripts\C>linked_list
> Success: lengthTest() length was 3
> Success: pushTest() length was: 5
> [0]: -1
> [1]: 0
> [2]: 1
> [3]: 2
> [4]: 3
> Success: pushTestEmpty() length was 1 after 1st push().
> Success: pushTestEmpty() length was 2 after 2nd push().
> [0]: 2
> [1]: 1
> Success: appendTest() length was: 5
> [0]: 1
> [1]: 2
> [2]: 3
> [3]: 4
> [4]: 5
> Success: appendTestEmpty() length was 1 after 1st append().
> Success: appendTestEmpty() length was 2 after 2nd append().
> [0]: 1
> [1]: 2
> ```

C is all new to me, and I've been made aware that there are many pitfalls in particular with pointer code, so I would like to learn as much as I can about the "right" way to do pointers, as well as any other possible improvements.

Note that this is intended to be for learning and there are no plans for this to be deployed in a production environment.

---

## `linked_list.h`

```c
// linked_list.h

#include <stdio.h>

extern struct Node;

extern int length(struct Node* head);

extern void printList(struct Node* head);

extern void push(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);

extern void append(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);

extern struct Node* buildTestListWithThreeNodes();

extern void lengthTest();

extern void pushTest();

extern void pushTestEmpty();

extern void appendTest();

extern void appendTestEmpty();

extern int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

---

## `linked_list.c`

```c
// linked_list.c

#include "linked_list.h"

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

/*
Calculates the number of elements that are in the linked list provided as argument.
*/
int length(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* current = head;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}

/*
Prints each element of the list along with its index to stdout.
*/
void printList(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* current = head;
    int nodeNum = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "[%d]: %d\n", nodeNum, current->data);
        current= current->next;
        nodeNum++;
    }
}

/*
Add a node at the front of the linked list, pushing the other elements towards the back.
If the list is empty, it adds the element being pushed as the first element.
*/
void push(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data) {
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    if (*headRefPtr == NULL) {
        newNode->next = NULL;
    } 
    else {
        newNode->next = *headRefPtr;
    }
    *headRefPtr = newNode;
}

/*
Add a node at the back of the linked list, after any existing elements.
If the list is empty, it adds the element as the first element.
*/
void append(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data) {
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*headRefPtr == NULL) {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        *headRefPtr = newNode;
    } 
    else {
        struct Node* current = *headRefPtr;
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}

/*
Manually builds a linked list of structure {1,2,3} for testing purposes.
*/
struct Node* buildTestListWithThreeNodes() {
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next = NULL;

    head->data = 1;
    second->data = 2;
    third->data = 3;
    
    return head;
}

/*
Tests the length() method for correctness.
*/
void lengthTest() {
    struct Node* list = buildTestListWithThreeNodes();
    int expectedLen = 3;
    int actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: lengthTest() expected length is %d, but actual length was%d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: lengthTest() length was %d\n", actualLen);
    }
    free(list);
}

/*
Tests the push() method for correctness using a non-empty list.
*/
void pushTest() {
    struct Node* list = buildTestListWithThreeNodes();
    push(&list, 0);
    push(&list, -1);
    int expectedLen = 5;
    int actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: pushTest() expected length %d, but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: pushTest() length was: %d\n", actualLen);
    }
    printList(list);
    free(list);
}

/*
Tests the push() method for correctness using a empty list.
*/
void pushTestEmpty() {
    struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list = NULL;
    /* test that pushing once to an empty list results in the first node being created: */
    push(&list, 1);
    int expectedLen = 1;
    int actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: pushTestEmpty() expected length %d after 1st push(), but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: pushTestEmpty() length was %d after 1st push().\n", actualLen);
    }
    /* test that the now non-empty list behaves like a non-empty list should when pushed to again: */
    push(&list, 2);
    expectedLen = 2;
    actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: pushTestEmpty() expected length %d after 2nd push(), but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: pushTestEmpty() length was %d after 2nd push().\n", actualLen);
    }
    printList(list);
    free(list);
}

/*
Tests the append() method for correctness using a non-empty list.
*/
void appendTest() {
    struct Node* list = buildTestListWithThreeNodes();
    append(&list, 4);
    append(&list, 5);
    int expectedLen = 5;
    int actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: appendTest() expected length %d, but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: appendTest() length was: %d\n", actualLen);
    }
    printList(list);
    free(list);
}

/*
Tests the append() method for correctness using a empty list.
*/
void appendTestEmpty() {
    struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list = NULL;
    /* test that appending once to an empty list results in the first node being created: */
    append(&list, 1);
    int expectedLen = 1;
    int actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: appendTestEmpty() expected length %d after 1st append(), but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: appendTestEmpty() length was %d after 1st append().\n", actualLen);
    }
    /* test that the now non-empty list behaves like a non-empty list should when pushed to again: */
    append(&list, 2);
    expectedLen = 2;
    actualLen = length(list);
    if (actualLen != expectedLen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: appendTestEmpty() expected length %d after 2nd append(), but actual length was %d\n", expectedLen, actualLen);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success: appendTestEmpty() length was %d after 2nd append().\n", actualLen);
    }
    printList(list);
    free(list);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    lengthTest();
    pushTest();
    pushTestEmpty();
    appendTest();
    appendTestEmpty();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to learn about pointers or about dynamic data structures (like list, tree) ?  Because you can do the latter with more modern languages using references.

Comment: For learning pointers, figure out the classic `while(*dst++ = *src++) ;`

Comment: Your buildtestwiththreenodes shpuld use your framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When declaring a function with an empty parameter list (as below), no information about parameters is known *nor tested* by the compiler.  Instead, use `void` to explicitly indicate that the function does not take any parameters.

   ```
   extern void lengthTest();
   lengthTest("abc", 123.4);  // appears to be valid code - no warning

   // better
   extern void lengthTest(void);
   lengthTest("abc", 123.4);  // invalid code - warning/error
   ```
2. If a function does not modify the pointer's contents, that parameter should be declared `const`.  This allows additional optimizations and improved error checking.  It also serves a documentation role, letting users of the function know nothing will be changed.

   ```
   // extern void printList(struct Node* head);
   extern void printList(const struct Node* head);
   ```
3. Namespace:  The set of function names have little in common.  I suggest appending a uniform prefix:

   ```
   // extern void printList(struct Node* head);
   // extern void push(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);
   // extern void append(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);
   extern void ll_print(const struct Node* head);
   extern void ll_push(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);
   extern void ll_append(struct Node** headRefPtr, int data);
   ```
4. Rather than allocate to the size of a structure, allocate to the size of the referenced object.  This is easier to code correctly, to review, and to maintain.

   ```
   //                    was this the right type?   
   // head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

   // Type specificity not needed.
   head = malloc(sizeof *head);
   ```
5. Remove redundant code:

   ```
   newNode->next = NULL;
   if (*headRefPtr == NULL) {
       // newNode->next = NULL; // code not needed
   ```
6. Good uniform formatting.
7. The following code allocates, assigns, and then ignores that with a subsequent assignment to the same variable. This looks odd—are you sure it is correct?

   ```
   struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   list = NULL;  // ??!!
   ```
8. Lack of error checking.  Code allocates, yet does not check if the allocation was successful.  Robust code must check for allocation failures (although they are rare, they can happen).  How the code handles and reports errors is a significant component of good design.

   ```
   struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

   // add some error handling
   if (newNode != NULL) TBD_ErrorHandler();

   newNode->data = data;
   ```
9. Header files should use include guards to protect against multiple inclusion. Although not a major issue in this case, it is a good practice to get into.

   ```
   // linked_list.h

   #ifndef linked_list_H
   #define linked_list_H 1

   #include <stdio.h>
   extern struct Node;
   ....

   #endif
   ```
10. It is strange to have `main()` in `linked_list.h`.  Best to remove.  Likewise, `int main(int argc, char **argv)` does not belong in `linked_list.c`, but perhaps `linked_list_test.h`.  Perhaps move the various test functions there, too.
11. I'd expect functions like `void pushTest();` to return an indication of success or error, maybe `int pushTest();`
12. (Minor:) I would use `extern unsigned length(const struct Node* head);` rather than `int`, but that is a larger code design issue.
13. Aside from test code, I see no `free()`.  An `ll_free(struct Node** headRefPtr)` should be written.
14. I'd also expect an `ll_pop()` function of some signature to extract a data element, as well as a `bool ll_IsEmpty(const struct Node*)`.

---

15. Now I present an advanced idea.  Rather than have the linked-list end with `NULL`, have the last element point to the first—a circular list.  Instead of the header pointing to the first element, point to the last element.  Walking a list is still simple: move to the first, and continue until the `next` field matches the first.  The key advantage is that a node can be added to the beginning or end of the list in O(1) time, without needing to traverse the entire list.

Comment: I agree with your #11, except that I would return a `bool` instead of an `int` (assuming that you don't need to return multiple error codes). I didn't change this in my suggested edit, though, because I didn't want to deviate that much from your intent.

Comment: asserts should only be used for detecting logic errors during debugging, never for valid runtime failures like running out of memory.

Comment: @JimBalter what is preferred for such runtime failures instead of `assert()`?

Comment: @Phrancis Well, first, something that is executed in release builds ... `assert` generally is not, so this failure would result in the program crashing with no indication why. So, some sort of error log or report ... most production software has an error reporting subsystem. Of course this is a problem in a library. As a rule, libraries shouldn't allocate ... let the caller allocate, or provide an allocation function to be called by the library.

Comment: @CodyGray `bool/int` meh - IAC, it does depend on overall design.  I selected `int` here as likely more familiar to OP.

Comment: @JimBalter Agree that using `assert()` was on over simplification.  Answer amended.  Error handling is a significant attribute of code set design which i wanted to avoid a small treatise.  I wanted to stress the need with a short sample idea.

Comment: @JimBalter Concerning `assert()` in run-time builds: Some run-time builds leave `assert()` active, in effect negating the `NDEBUG` macro.  Again, this is part of the larger error handling design and varies amongst group's coding standards.

Comment: That's why I said "generally".

Answer (score 7):

### The header file

#### Extern keyword

In C, function declarations are `extern` by default, so you don't have to use an explicit `extern` keyword.  In fact, I never use `extern` for functions, only for variables.  Also, I'm not sure if `extern struct node;` is even legal C.  That should certainly just be `struct node;` to make a forward declaration of the struct.

#### Void arguments

In C, there is a difference between function declarations with empty parentheses and functions with a `void` argument:

```
int foo();
int foo(void);
```

The first means that the function can accept any arguments (including none).  The second means that the function can only accept no arguments.  This is not the same for other languages.  For example, java requires empty parentheses.  C++ treats the two the same (i.e. no arguments).

#### Limit function exports

In a header file, you should only declare functions that want to *export*, meaning you want other source files to be able to call those functions.  In your header file, you've exported everything, including `main()`.  I don't think you should be exporting your test functions or `main()`, because it doesn't seem likely that those functions will be used elsewhere.  Instead, those functions should probably be made `static` within linked_list.c.  in fact, there should probably be three files:

```
linked_list.h
linked_list.c      (only the linked list code)
linked_list_test.c (main and all the test functions)
```

#### Including other headers

Right now, linked_list.h includes `<stdio.h>`.  There's actually no reason for it to do so, because nothing in the linked_list.h actually uses anything from that header.  You may have put it there just so that you don't have to include `<stdio.h>` in each of your .c files, which is fine.  However, if you make it a habit to put all your system includes in your headers, you may wind up including a lot of unnecessary headers when you compile.

### The c file

#### Consider using a typedef

Consider doing `typedef struct Node Node;` so that everywhere you use `struct Node` you can just use `Node` instead.  It's just a bit easier to read that way.

#### length() function

1. In your `length()` function, you use a temp variable called `current` to walk through your linked list.  You can actually get rid of that variable and just use `head` instead.
2. The function returns an `int` but your count variable is an `unsigned int`.  Probably the function should return an `unsigned int` or even a `size_t`.
3. The input argument is unmodified, so you can mark it `const`.

Rewrite:

```
size_t length(const Node *head)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while (head != NULL) {
        count++;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

#### printList()

I would replace `fprintf(stdout, ...)` with just `printf(...)`.  They are equivalent, but again it is just easier to read the shorter version.

#### push()

I see a call to `malloc()` but I didn't see `#include <stdlib.h>`.  This could be bad because the compiler might think that `malloc()` returns an `int` instead of a pointer.  On a 64-bit target, that could cause a crash.  Be sure to compile with warnings turned on to catch these sorts of bugs.

This code here:

> ```
> if (*headRefPtr == NULL) {
>     newNode->next = NULL;
> } 
> else {
>     newNode->next = *headRefPtr;
> }
> ```

can be simplified to just:

```
newNode->next = *headRefPtr;
```

#### lengthTest()

You print your fail messages to `stderr` and your success messages to `stdout`.  For a test program, I would just print everything to `stdout`.  Otherwise you might do `runtest > results.txt` and not notice that the error messages were being printed to the console and not saved to the file.

When you do `free(list)` you are creating a memory leak because you are only freeing the first node, not every node in the list.

#### pushTest() and appendTest()

You test the length of the list, but you only print the contents instead of checking them.  You should make sure that the list contains the expected items in the expected order, so that the reader of the output doesn't have to read the code in order to determine whether the printed list is correct or not.

#### appendListEmpty()

Another memory leak here, but probably a typo:

> ```
> struct Node* list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
> list = NULL;
> ```

Comment: Would I need to include `linked_list.c` within `linked_list_test.c` or only include the `linked_list.h` in the tests?

Comment: You would only need to include `linked_list.h` from within each of the `.c` files.